# THERE IS something you want to say, ISN'T THERE/RIGHT? (Question tag)

Tags: tag-questions

Regarding forming question tags, grammar books teach us:

> **There is** something you want to say, **isn't there?** (this is the ideal)

Vs.

> > **There is** something you want to say, **right**?

Can it still be correct to ask people using sentence#2? In movies, I think sentence#2 usage is more frequent...

Comment: They're both perfectly valid, but this use of ***Right?*** is far more colloquial / informal than ***Isn't there?***

Comment: I don't have conclusive evidence for it but I have a sense that (1) is more likely in British English and (2) is more likely in American English.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, Yes, I think so too. Most of the movies I have watched since I was a kid were American, but when I started to improve my English such as watching many British films/video clips online, 'sentence1' was frequent from Brits. -you have spelled this out.

Comment: The first version sounds far more natural to me. (I'm Canadian, which leaves me confused and placed firmly between US and UK English..) However, **neither** really sounds natural to me. I'd be more inclined to say *Is there something you want to say?*

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'm not sure about how common they are but, as a British speaker, I'd expect the tone to be rather different. "... right?" is rather informal.